# ICACLS escape asterisk character

Tags: windows-command-prompt, icacls

Let's say I have managed to create a file named '*' (via MSYS or whatever)

Is there a way to properly escape this such that I can call ICACLS and only list that single file?

`icacls *` lists everything in the directory

The file itself shows up as

[image: ]

and apparently entering `icacls ` works, but I can't really see a way of reliably escaping this character given arbitrary input. Surely there's a better solution than just replacing `*` with `` ?

Comment: FYI, the `` character (Unicode `U+F02A`, UTF-8 `0xEF,0x80,0xAA`) belongs to Unicode _Private Use_ area…

Answer (score 0):

Surely there's *no* solution in pure `cmd`.

1. `*` (asterisk) is one of illegal characters in names for files and directories in windows, regardless of the file system:

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
> Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
> (128–255), [except for the following](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions):
>
> The following reserved characters:
>
> ```
> < (less than)
> > (greater than)
> : (colon)
> " (double quote)
> / (forward slash)
> \ (backslash)
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
> ? (question mark)
> * (asterisk)
> ```

2. In a few commands, you can use [wildcard characters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) (`*` or `?`), to represent one or more characters of a file name. However, it's not a regex-like, you can't escape them…